# When did the MSDN search include SO results?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I was just using MSDN search, and discovered I could filter by source, and SO was one of the filter options.

[image: SO Search on MSDN]

I have never noticed this before (although, I don't use the MSDN search that often, Google tends to suffice), when was this nice little addition implemented, or did Microsoft just do it without any input from SE?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've been seeing SO results on MSDN for a while, I think at least a year or two. This isn't a recent thing.

Comment: @Gilles: ah, my mistake; I thought the Visual Studio integration coincided. I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joel [announced the integration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-results-featured-in-msdn-search/) on October 29th, 2010, which I roughly remember being a day or so after it being launched.

Comment: Wow, I have never noticed this before.. says something about how often I use the MSDN search, or my attention to detail.